# Update bean message value before displaying it in a <p:confirmDialog>

Tags: jsf, primefaces, message, confirm

Can anyone tell me how do I change the message of `<p: confirm>`? When you click the button I want the message of value to be returned by the `messageCount ()` method.

```
...

<p:outputLabel value="Test:" />                        
<p:inputText value="#{testController.fieldTest}" id="fieldTest"/>

...

<p:commandButton value="Ok" action="#{testController.cadTest()}">
    <p:confirm id="messageConfirm" header="Test" />
</p:commandButton>

...

<p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">
    <f:facet name="message">
        <p:outputPanel>
            <h:outputFormat id="message" value="#{testController.mensagemConfirm}" escape="false"/>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </f:facet>
    <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" />
    <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" />
</p:confirmDialog>

...


//TestController

private String mensagemConfirm;
private Integer count = 0;


public Integer messageCount() {
    return count++;
}

public String getMensagemConfirm() {
    setMessageConfirm("Count: " + messageCount());
    return mensagemConfirm;
}

public void setMensagemConfirm(String mensagemConfirm) {
    this.mensagemConfirm = mensagemConfirm;
}
```

Example:

- First Click the "Ok" (`<p:commandButton>`)

  -> message of confirmDialog: **Count: 1** (click in "No")
- Secound Click the "Ok" (`<p:commandButton>`)

  -> message of confirmDialog: **Count: 2** (click in "No")
- Third Click the "Ok" (`<p:commandButton>`)

  -> message of confirmDialog: **Count: 3** (click in "No")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the p:confirm will not execute your server side code until you press "yes" in the confirmDialog. So you have to do something in order to execute the server side code first, and show the confirm dialog after the ajax request has been completed.

You can do it by showing the confirm dialog with the oncomplete attribute:

```
    <p:commandButton value="Ok" update="conf" action="#{testController.increaseCount()}" oncomplete="PF('confirmVar').show()"/>

    <p:confirmDialog id="conf" global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" widgetVar="confirmVar">

        <p:commandButton value="Yes" action="#{testController.cadTest()}" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" oncomplete="PF('confirmVar').hide()"/>
        <p:commandButton value="No" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" oncomplete="PF('confirmVar').hide()"/>

        <f:facet name="message">
            <p:outputPanel>
                <h:outputFormat value="Count: #{testController.count}" escape="false"/>
            </p:outputPanel>
        </f:facet>
    </p:confirmDialog>
```

Also its bad design to execute application logic code in pure getters/setters. Use dedicated methods for that.

testController bean:

```
private int count;

public int getCount() {
    return count;
}

public void setCount(int count) {
    this.count = count;
}

public void increaseCount() {
   count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By your explanation, it seems that you only want to increment the `count` value after the users hits the "No"

So, you could use the `actionListener` property inside the commandButton, which will call the increment method using ajax request:

```
<p:commandButton value="No"  actionListener="#{testController.incrementCount()}" ajax="true" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close"/>
```

- Note that I removed the property `type=button`, if I didn't, it wouldn't call the method

To show the current value:

```
 <h:outputFormat id="message" value="Count: #{testController.count}" escape="false"/>
```

Controller:

```
Integer count = 0;
public void incrementCount() {
   count++;
}
public Integer getCount(){
   return count;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ... But I need increments the **count** after clicking on the **Ok** ... Assuming I click **No** and then **Ok** again would have increments too . That is ... I click **OK** , falls controller and increments and shows on the confirmation screen. tks